# How can I update values of a column in a dataframe based on its existence in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
from IPython.display import display, HTML
dict_1 = {'col1':range(0,21),'col3':0}
dict_2 = {'col2':range(0,41,4)}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dict_2)
```

So the goal is to compare all the values in `df['col1']` in `df_2['col2']` and for each row that equals the other I need to update col3 to 1 or some value other than what it is now

in this case I am looking for something of the sort:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,20],'col3':[1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]}
```

Comment: Something like `df.merge(df_2, left_on='col1', right_on='col2')[['col1']].assign(col3=1)` ?

Comment: @HenryEcker not quite that generates a new data frame and, I realize that is not what I am looking for, I am trying to update the existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) + [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col1'].isin(df_2['col2']), 1, 0)
```

`df.head()`:

```
    col1  col3
0      0     1
1      1     0
2      2     0
3      3     0
4      4     1
```

Edit to include `col4` with left [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to set values based on where `col4` (values from `df2`) is `nan`:

Given

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': range(0, 21), 'col3': 0})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [0, 4, 8, 12, 16],
                     'col4': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
```

```
df = df.merge(
    df_2, left_on='col1', right_on='col2', how='left'
).drop(columns='col2').fillna('')
df['col3'] = np.where(df['col4'].isna(), 0, 1)
```

`df.head()`:

```
    col1  col3 col4
0      0     1    a
1      1     0     
2      2     0     
3      3     0     
4      4     1    b
```

Comment: how should I proceed if I want to to change multiple columns value based on the result from np.where(). So lets say df had another column named col 4 and I wanted that to equal to col2 when ever it matched up with col1.

Comment: Not quite, col 3 just checks for availability and col 4 retains value from df_2 when values match up.

Comment: I updated ur sol under merge starting at df=, basically df is the expected result on the merge of df and df_2

Comment: Wait, actually there was a typo.

Comment: does what I said make sense?

Comment: Again, it would be best if you would edit your question to outline what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly with pandas:

```
df_1['col3'] = df_1['col1'].isin(df_2['col2']).astype(int)
```